# Criação correta de View no MVC usando Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho uma página que realiza a manutenção de um orçamento.

Abaixo apresento um *briefing* das entidades

```
public partial class Orcamento
{
    public int IdPedidoCompra { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}

public partial class OrcamentoItem
{
    public int IdOrcamentoItem { get; set; }
    public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecoUnitario { get; set; }
}

public partial class Historico
{
    public int IdHistorico { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdOrcamento { get; set; }
    public string NomeContato { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataContato { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataProximoContato { get; set; }
}
```

Com base nessas tabelas eu criei minha *view* fortemente tipada com `Orcamento`

```
@model HT.Dominio.Entidade.Orcamento
```

E os campos de `OrcamentoItem` e `Historico` eu coloquei na mão, ou seja, sem a utilização dos `Html.Helpers`.

Com isso eu perco as validações que o MVC já cria pra mim ao utilizar o *Helper* `ValidationMessageFor`, entre outros problemas também.

Para salvar eu estou fazendo tudo via Ajax, preenchendo tudo na mão, um trabalho danado.

```
    //cria o objeto json
    var orcamento = {"campo1", "campo2"....}
    var orcamentoitens = {"campo1", "campo2"....}
    //preenche o objeto

    //envia ao servidor
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Orcamento/Salvar/",
        data: JSON.stringify(orcamento),
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (retorno) {}
    });
```

Então eu pergunto: Qual a maneira correta de se fazer isso?

Separo em *forms* na *view* para cada entidade e envia através de `submit`, ou crio em *partialview* e chamo cada um no seu lugar? Ou deixo tudo como está e vamos embora?

Obrigado, pessoal!

Comment: Qual o motivo de você não utilizar os *Helpers* em HTML?

Comment: Ola Cigano, acho que mais por falta de experiencias com o MVC.
Agora lendo alguns artigos estou pensando em separar tudo em PartialView.

Comment: Sim, é o correto. Aliás, [o MVC já é preparado para Ajax](http://ninjadevspace.com/mvc-3-ajax-begin-form/). Você só precisa aprender a usar as extensões.

Answer (score 1):

O legal e para o bom aproveitamento dos binds do MVC é criando views tipadas mesmo. Você poderia criar um modelo de apresentação (uma classe no model) que englobe Orcamento, OrcamentoItem e Historico. ex: "ApresentacaoOrcamento". Isso porque antes de alimentar a sua View você provavelmente consulta alguma base, assim é só preencher sua ApresentacaoOrcamento. 
Com isso, na ida até a View e na volta com o POST você irá usufruir das validações utilizando sua ApresentacaoOrcamento. Além disso fica simples a sua manipulação.

**No model**

```
public class ApresentacaoOrcamento
{
Orcamento MeuOrcamento;
List<OrcamentoItem> MeuOrcamentoItem;
Historico MeuOrcamentoHistorico;
}
```

**No controller**

```
public ActionResult SeuMetodoQueChamaAView()
{
var apresentacao = new ApresentacaoOrcamento();
apresentacao.MeuOrcamento = meuRepositorio.GetOrcamentoById(1);
apresentacao.MeuOrcamentoItem = meuRepositorio.GetItensByOrcamentoId(1).toList();
apresentacao.MeuOrcamentoHistorico = meuRepositorio.GetHistoricoByOrcamentoId(1);
return View(apresentacao);
}
```

**Na View**

```
@model HT.Models.ApresentacaoOrcamento
```

**No POST**

Ao postar o objeto ApresentacaoOrcamento em um método POST que receba (ApresentacaoOrcamento apresentacaoOrcamento).
Seu objeto virá montado.

Esta é a maneira que quase sempre procedi em minhas implementações. As vezes ocorre de ter que manipular mais o objeto a ser enviado Via post quando tenho problemas de Bind.